# Cannot read property value on nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, Im checking for changed props in my componentWillReceiveProps function. But Im getting a null error. Code:

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.author.id!= nextProps.author.id) {
            debugger;
            this.setState({author: Object.assign({}, nextProps.author)});
        }
    }
```

When setting debbugger i seem to have values, but then chrome says it is undefined:
[image: Image of error]

Whats making me even more confused is that when i add a debugger for the runthrough of code, its not giving me any errors and the author Im getting the nextProps from gets populated into the input fields, but I still get the above error afterwards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it occurs when variable is undefined.

How abount this code?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if ((this.props.author && this.props.author.id) !== (nextProps.author && nextProps.author.id)) {
```

Comment: Here you're comparing two booleans, instead of checking they exist and then comparing. It should be
`if ((this.props.author && nextProps.author) && (this.props.author.id !== nextProps.author.id)) {`, which will only execute the second check if both are are defined.

Comment: None of these examples are working. I can see that i hit this function twice, the first time props.author is populated, but the nextProps.author is undefined. The second time this.props.author is undefined but nextProp is populated. Since one of them is missing in each case I know dont set the author state at all.

Two thoughts, why do I enter this function twice, and why does each propportion of the componentWillReceiveProps come up empty?

Comment: Could you call the initial setState in the constructor, and check nextProps vs the current state?